# Erlang: skip first bytes of binary

Tags: erlang

I have binary packet with header (undetermined length sequence of `\FF` bytes) and following structured body that i need to parse. Example packets:
`<<255,255,255,255,255,6,8,0,0,1>>`,
`<<255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,10,15,0,0,1>>`

What is the most efficient way to parse it? I've came to the following solution:

1) Convert packet to list

2) Skip the header with following fun:

```
skip_elem([E | Rest], Condition) ->
  case Condition(E) of
    true -> [E | Rest];
    false -> skip_elem(Rest, Condition)
  end;

skip_elem([], _Cond) -> [].
```

3) Convert list to binary and parse its body with binary matching features

But it seems complex and ineffective way, are there more effective solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this do what you needed?

```erlang
behead(<< 255, Packet/binary >>) ->
    behead(Packet);
behead(Packet) when is_binary(Packet) ->
    Packet.
```

For example:

```erlang
1> behead(<<255,255,255,255,255,6,8,0,0,1>>).
<<6,8,0,0,1>>
2> behead(<<255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,10,15,0,0,1>>).
<<10,15,0,0,1>>
```

For more details see the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html).